# Assimp Load Changed data

Tags: c++, import, export, assimp

I am using `Assimp` to import and export 3D models in c++. I load some data to `aiScene` then use `aiExportScene` to export my model.

When I import the saved model it loads correctly but the data has changed from the what i inserted. I need my original data to use in my processing.

I used `OBJ` and `GLTF` model and neither of them preserved my original data.

How can I export and import without my data changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not at the moment this is not supported. We have to do a transfer from the incoming data into an intermediate dataformat, which is in use for the export as well.
What you can do is avoiding any postprocessing steps at the end.

You are not the first one who is asking for this feature. So I will open a feature-request for this.

Comment: Thanks @KimKulling for your response. I would be great-full if you do this